# Python extending list recursively

Tags: python, algorithm, backtracking

I'm having some difficulty in understanding how Python works in the situation presented below.

I'm computing all permutations of a list recursively, and I want to return a list of lists with all those permutations. Code works fine if i just print them out, but if i try to extend the final [result] i end up with a list of lists with the same value as my input list (sorry for repeating the word list)

This is my code:

```
def swap(l, i, j):
  l[i], l[j] = l[j], l[i]

def compute(l):
  if not len(l):
    print 'no list'
  start, end = 0, len(l) - 1
  return _compute(l, start, end)

def _compute(l, start, end):
  res = []
  if start == end:
    return [l]
  else:
    for i in range(start, end+1):
      swap(l, start, i)
      res.extend(_compute(l, start+1, end))
      swap(l, start, i) # backtrack
  return res

l = [1,2,3]
print compute(l)
```

And the result:

```
[[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]
```

Like i said, if i just print out the results it works as expected:

```
def swap(l, i, j):
  l[i], l[j] = l[j], l[i]

def compute(l):
  if not len(l):
    print 'no list'
  start, end = 0, len(l) - 1
  _compute(l, start, end)


def _compute(l, start, end):
  if start == end:
    print l
  else:
    for i in range(start, end+1):
      swap(l, start, i)
      _compute(l, start+1, end)
      swap(l, start, i) # backtrack

l = [1,2,3]

compute(l)
```

The output:

```
[1, 2, 3]
[1, 3, 2]
[2, 1, 3]
[2, 3, 1]
[3, 2, 1]
[3, 1, 2]
```

Why?

Comment: You each time add a **reference** to the **same** list. So modifications to the list in one branch are reflected in the other branch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python works with objects. Variables refer to objects. If you add the list to the resulting list, and then make modifications, the list in your result will thus reflect those changes.

You thus should make at least a *shallow* copy. You can this for instance with:

```
def _compute(l, start, end):
  res = []
  if start == end:
    return [l[:]]  # make a shallow copy
  else:
    for i in range(start, end+1):
      swap(l, start, i)
      res.extend(_compute(l, start+1, end))
      swap(l, start, i) # backtrack
  return res

l = [1,2,3]
print compute(l)
```

Nevertheless, this code fragment is still quite inefficient, and hard to understand. Note that `not(len(l))` does not check if the object has a `len(..)`: it checks if `len(l)` is zero. You thus should use `isinstance(..)`.

A more efficient approach would be to construct the `res` list once, and pass it through the system collection results. For example:

```
def _compute(l):
  def _calc(start, end, res):
    if start < end-1:
        for i in range(start,end):
          swap(l,start,i)
          _calc(start+1, end, res)
          swap(l,start,i)
    else:
      res.append(l[:])
    return res
  return _calc(0, len(l), [])
```

Comment: Right, i see the issue now. Need to go more in depth of how Python works.
Thanks a lot Willem for pointing the issue out and providing a better solution